# Java TypedQuery much slower than directly querying DB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an application that needs to select a potentially very large number of rows (several hundred thousand to millions).

When I run my query directly against my database (Oracle) it returns in ~9-10s and selects 4M rows.

When I execute the same SQL as a TypedQuery it times out after 5 minutes.

I've tried paging, hibernate scrollableresults, setting the query read only, disabling caching and even tried a nativeQuery but nothing seems to help.

Sample code below:

```
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
sql.append("SELECT t from TestResult t WHERE t.endDatetime >= ");
sql.append(getDateSelector(timestampStart));
sql.append(" AND t.endDatetime <= ");
sql.append(getDateSelector(timestampEnd));
sql.append(" ORDER BY t.nodeId, t.endDatetime DESC");

TypedQuery<TestResult> query = entityManager.createQuery(sql.toString(), TestResult.class);

testResults = query.getResultList();
```

Paginated example:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public List<TestResult> iterateAllTestResults(String startDateTime, String endDateTime)
{
    int offset = 0;
    List<TestResult> allTestResults = new ArrayList<>();

    List<TestResult> testResults;
    while ((testResults = this.getAllTestResultsIterableHelper(offset, 100, startDateTime, endDateTime)).size() > 0)
    {
        allTestResults.addAll(testResults);
        offset += testResults.size();
    }

    return allTestResults;
}

private List<TestResult> getAllTestResultsIterableHelper(int offset, int max, String startDateTime, String endDateTime)
{

    try
    {
        Timestamp timestampStart = DateTimeFormatter.convertFormattedDateToTimestamp(startDateTime);
        Timestamp timestampEnd = DateTimeFormatter.convertFormattedDateToTimestamp(endDateTime);

        StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
        sql.append("SELECT t from TestResult t WHERE t.endDatetime >= ");
        sql.append(getDateSelector(timestampStart));
        sql.append(" AND t.endDatetime <= ");
        sql.append(getDateSelector(timestampEnd));
        sql.append(" ORDER BY t.nodeId, t.endDatetime DESC");

        List<TestResult> results = entityManager.().createQuery(sql.toString(), TestResult.class).setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(max).getResultList();

        return results;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // omitted
    }
}
```

Is there some option or technique I am missing/could use to do this better?

Comment: I see no pagination here

Comment: And thr way you qreate your query insteed of using prepared statement is a nightmare

Comment: Added paginated example.

Comment: By directly you mean via some sort of Gui management studio right? Most probably limit is added to every select if not specified so that explains time difference.

Comment: umm so you paginate result but you still fetch 4M records but in loop? why? it will take even longer . from your rescription I understood that fetching eg 100 rows takies 5 minutes

Comment: Yes, when I say directly I mean I am using SQL Developer.

Comment: why do you need 4 millions of rows AT ONCE?

Comment: sql dev as precaution will limit select anyway. try manual limit to 1000000 and you will se that it will take minutes as well

Comment: I need to have all rows in memory so I can do very specific analysis to it. The reason I tried paginating is because selecting the 4M rows all at once was failing.

Comment: Is the `endDatetime` column indexed? 4M rows will anyways take time to process, but checking Oracle's EXPLAIN PLAN output for the query could tell you if there is something you could change in the query itself.

Comment: Yes, endDatetime is indexed. I'll have a look at the explain plan but it's looking like I'll probably have to rethink how the analysis is done.

Answer (score 1):

It because in Java you tries to fetch all 4 millions of records while in your Oracle studio, you have limit added by studio as a precaution (only 50 rows or so i assume? or maybe 1000 like in mysql workbench?). If you think that you are fetching 4m rows in 9 seconds with sorting then I am not buying it.

Anyway, fetching 4M into application is rather bad ide for whatever reason. You should try to move your "analysis" to  the database, or rethink processing so you will use only some part od all results at once. That is what pagination is used for. If you rly want to get all rows, well you will have to wait 5 minutes every time you need it.

Comment: In SQLDeveloper when I add a AND rownum <= 5000 or AND rownum <= 500000 or AND rownum <= 5000000 I get results in an amount of time that changes corresponding to the results. Several milliseconds for 5000, ~5s for 500000, and about 10-20s for 5000000. I believe SQL Developer fetches all the data and only displays 50.

Comment: No it does not as it would be stupidity. The only thing that changes there is the result pool thah has to be SORTED thus time differences. So, more to sort, more time it takes. And still only 50 rows are fetched. Your "benchmarking" is simply wrong

Comment: Good point, that probably does explain the variance in times I am seeing.